# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch

Tags: java, maven, guava, nosuchmethoderror

I've found an identical thread: [NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855559/nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-base-stopwatch-createstartedlcom-google-c)

but the solution seems not working for me.

The exception is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createUnstarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch
```

and is raised by:

```
at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil$4.get(GrpcUtil.java:566)
at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil$4.get(GrpcUtil.java:563)
```

Only Guava 20.0 seems present in my Classpath (I'm using Maven) so no older version can conflcits.

This is a snippet of my `mvn dependency:tree` output

```
[INFO] |  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:jar:1.29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.23.0:compile
```

If I search for Guava, this the only entry that I can see.

In the target folder the buil WAR => WEB-INF/lib has only guava-20.jar, no visible duplication.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Does your execution environment provide an older version of guava?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen probably yes, I need to check. I've just noticed that the problem occurs with Weblogic but works fine with Apache Tomcat.

Comment: You may want to look into running with `mvn jetty:run`. This makes this kind of investigation much easier.

Comment: Well, since you mention Weblogic, your question is actually a duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weblogic Prefer application packages not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375774/weblogic-prefer-application-packages-not-working)

Comment: the problem was that Weblogic embed an older version of that library so that was the conflict, I've excluded the Weblogic version and now it works