# MyFaces basic project won't start

Tags: java, myfaces

I'm trying to launch a very basic project found here:

[The HelloWorld example of JSF 2.2 with Myfaces](https://vhandit.blogspot.com/2016/05/helloworld-jsf-2.2-myfaces.html)

Just cloned the git from [here](https://github.com/vnnvanhuong/jsf_myfaces).

Now, I've tried different approach but just can't amend the JSF Mojarra co-existence in my App Server, since I think that this problem:

```
<27-ott-2018 23.44.46,046 CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 9 task for the application "jsf_myfaces" on [partition-name: DOMAIN].> 
<27-ott-2018 23.44.46,048 CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "jsf_myfaces".> 
<27-ott-2018 23.44.46,048 CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:561)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getApplication(FacesContextImplBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.FacesContextImplBase.getELContext(FacesContextImplBase.java:231)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.setLocale(UIViewRoot.java:1488)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Is just related to that.
Tried JBoss Wildfly 8.2 and Weblogic 12c R2, same story.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369903/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897900/java-lang-illegalstateexceptioncould-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-ap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the correct way to start the project keeping myfaces dependencies jars in front of the ones in the server container:

[weblogic-prefer-application-packages-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375774/weblogic-prefer-application-packages-not-working)

Probably a simple deployment-descriptor for JBoss would accomplish the same task.